# external json file is not being loaded from desktop

Tags: json

I am having trouble loading external json file in `<script>`.

```
     <script>
         function get_data()
        { 
         $.ajax(
          {
       type: "GET", 
       url:"json.json", 
         dataType:"json", 
         async: true,       
         success:function(mainObject)
        { 
            if (mainObject.text) 
                { var JSONa = JSON.parse(mainObject.text); } 
            else
                { var JSONa = mainObject; }
        }
      }
    );
     }
    get_data();
   </script>
```

Ths json file is on desktop and the html file is also on desktop. The filename is corect, and I have also tried giving url as url:"C:\Users\jathaker\Desktop\json.json".

Comment: What error do you get in the console log?

Comment: This is in html file... so firebug doesnt give any error

Comment: I just cannot see the json object data loaded in firebug.